# Error OPTIONS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-chrome

I am developing a web application using "jQuery"(front-end) and "Python"(back-end). While making a PUT request to update details in the database, this is the error I get in the console:

> OPTIONS "REST API URL" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My jQuery code is:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "PUT",
    url: "REST API URL",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": AuthToken},
    data: "details to be updated in database",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data,status) {
      //do something with data
    },
    error: function(data,status) {
      //show error data and status
    }
)};
```

I read about how HTTP Requests other than `GET` and `POST` are first pre-flighted as OPTIONS request and only when it is a genuine request, it gets processed as a `PUT/DELETE/PATCH` request.
I saw solutions where it said that it might be a `CORS` issue, but `CORS` is **enabled** from the back-end to allow `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE` requests. Further, I am successfully able to make `GET` and `POST` requests but no `PUT` requests are going through.
I am using "Chrome Dev Tools" and researched about how to fix this error for Chrome by clearing cache and cookies, flushing DNS and re-installing Chrome but none of the solutions have worked so far.
I am a making the front end UI and am not sure whether this is a client-side error or a server-side error?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: url: "REST API URL" , you know this has to be the real api url right ?

Comment: I used the real API but forgot to mention the port number. A very silly mistake from my end.
Thanks

Answer (score 22):

One thing is for sure, this is a backend problem. This happens when the cross origin communication between the backend and frontend is not connected properly. Considering you have imported cors and set up the middleware, most probably you have made a mistake using the PUT method in terms of the origin URL and request URL.

Things you can do:

1) Make sure both servers are running (the back-end and front end).

2) Look into google development tool and see the network section. Look at the request headers and the general. Make sure the **request URL / backend** has your backend server URL and the **orgin / frontend** has your frontend URL.

3) Make sure in your http.put() method, the domain you are feeding it matches the api you set up in your server.

4) Your issue is that your backend is not connected with your front end properly,so don't waste your time trying to find other errors. Focus on debuging the http.put() method and the cors module and middleware you have imported.

Comment: Another thing to check is - can the backend be accessed directly outside of frontend code? I had an error like this and the problem was a misconfigured server file in Python (I had configured it for localhost so it stopped working on a hosted web server).

Comment: Yeah, ofcourse you have to change the url when deploying it to a host server.

Comment: front and end needs to be running otherwise you see this error

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact it is really a CORS issue - browsers 'preflight' the request using OPTIONS method. After the OPTIONS request **succeeds** the actual request (in your case PUT) is made.

Make sure, the backend responds to OPTION requests. You could easily catch all OPTION requests and return `200 OK` or `204 NO CONTENT`.

Comment: The back-end is configured to allow CORS by allowing GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/OPTIONS requests.
Although the problem is only occurring for PUT request and PATCH requests. GET and POST requests are successfully being sent.

Comment: What means configured ? You need to respond to the OPTIONS 'preflight' ! The preflight is required for non-simple (PUT, DELETE, ...) requests. Review the official Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) under 'Preflighted requests'. It might be helpful, when you share backend code and how you allow CORS.

Comment: I have a Django server, in which the settings.py file has the following code to allow CORS:
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
'GET',
'POST',
'PUT',
'PATCH',
'DELETE',
'OPTIONS'
)

Comment: It was my silly mistake. I forgot to mention the port number while making the API call. Thank you for your help.