# Connection refused when downloading file on a local area PC using proxy to backend

Tags: angular

This is my setup. I run the Angular app and Angular app on a PC in my local area network.

I have a function that when clicked opens a pdf file in another window.

```
openPdf(element: Acte) {
this.acteService.getPdf(element.url).subscribe((response) => {
  let file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileUrl);
 });
 }
```

element.url will be something like http://localhost:8080/api/download/file.pdf

My service:

```
getPdf(name: string) {

const httpOpt = {
  'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
};
return this.http.get<any>(name, httpOpt);
}
```

I follow these guidelines to proxy my backend.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

All my links in angular are /api/something...

My spring controller looks like :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileDownloadController {
private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "./download/";
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
public void downloadPDFResource(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) 
throws IOException {
   File file = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + fileName);
   if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("exista ");
        String mimeType = 
URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
        if (mimeType == null) {
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(
                "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""
        ));
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new 
 FileInputStream(file));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

My app currently runs locally so i launch ng serve --host 0.0.0.0. On another pc in localhost i can run the app on the pc`s ip and adding :4200 port. The problem is that when i click the button i get"

"OPTIONS: http://localhost:8080/api/download/myfile.pdf net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in my console. This doesn't happen on the pc that runs spring app and angular app.

All other controllers are accessible from another PC in the network, i just have problem with /download
What am i missing ?

In regard to CORS issues, this is my webmvcconfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
}
}
```

I have 12 controllers in my spring, this is the only controllers that has problems on another PC in the network, all of the others returning ok status.

EDIT:

My security config is :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/socket").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
            
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 }
```

Comment: This looks like a cross origin request issue, the options call is a preflight check before the actual request gets made. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request also this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115309/error-options-neterr-connection-refused

Comment: I added my cors settings. I don't think it has something to do with cors. I think it has something to do with proxy backend.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue in my project, which runs with Angular and Spring boot as well.

I think it's a CORS issue and, just like you, I included the CORS configuration.
Nonetheless, what solved my problem was including the CORS configuration at applications.properties.

What I did:

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allow-credentials=* # Whether credentials are supported. When not set, credentials are not supported.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers=* # Comma-separated list of headers to allow in a request. '*' allows all headers.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=* # Comma-separated list of methods to allow. '*' allows all methods. When not set, defaults to GET.
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=* # Comma-separated list of origins to allow. '*' allows all origins. When not set, CORS support is disabled.
management.endpoints.web.cors.exposed-headers=* # Comma-separated list of headers to include in a response.
management.endpoints.web.cors.max-age=3600s
```

Comment: I have commented out my cors settings and tried with yours cors settings and i get the same behavior: connection refused from another pc in the network, ok status from the pc on which the angular and spring boot app runs. I think it has something to do with the proxy backend. This request is not getting proxied and i don't undestand why ...

Comment: Are using spring security? If yes, remember to add `http.cors();` in your configuration!

Comment: Yes, i am using spring security. this is my configure method: @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/socket").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()