# Connection refused by Axios.post with SendGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, sendgrid

I recently graduated from a coding bootcamp and I am working on my React web portfolio. I want to add a contact form that takes in a visitors name, email, and message then emails me that information. To that end I followed along with a guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqmLxgvof70&list=PLnpdZyv-BjINbUjmTUsyziHz_4fa9hM5G&). However I am getting an error...

```
Error: Network Error                                                      ContactPage.js:56 
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

POST http://localhost:3030/api/email net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED         xhr.js:177
```

The error can be traced back to this Axios.post...

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3030/api/email", this.state)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.success) {
          this.setState({
            disabled: false,
            emailSent: true,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            disabled: false,
            emailSent: false,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);

        this.setState({
          disabled: false,
          emailSent: false,
        });
      });
```

I am not sure what is going wrong any any help will be appreciated.

Here is some backend code.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const sendGrid = require("@sendGrid/mail");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

app.get("/api", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("API Status: Running");
});

app.post("/api/email", (req, res, next) => {
//   sendGrid.setApiKey('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');
  sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: "agcmarcus@gmail.com",
    from: req.body.email,
    subject: "Portfolio Contact",
    text: req.body.message,
  };

  sendGrid
    .send(msg)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
      });
    });
});

app.listen(3030, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Have you enabled [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on your API?

Comment: I have, but in a different file. The one that has the app.post route.

Comment: Huh. It's hard to say without seeing any of your backend code. If you can post it here, that would be helpful! Additionally, you might want to check out this answer for a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247822/4668680

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that thread. I edited my comment to include back end code.

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate the error you're seeing. Perhaps it's a firewall issue? Or perhaps `localhost` isn't mapped to `0.0.0.0` on your machine?

Comment: How would I map 0.0.0.0 to localhost?